# git fetch fails due to pack-object failure

Tags: git, git-clone, git-fetch

When I add our remote repository as upstream and try to fetch it , it fails as below :

```
    $ git fetch upstream
    remote: Counting objects: 11901, done.
    remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
    error: pack-objects died of signal 9
    error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
    fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the re
    mote side.
    fatal: protocol error: bad pack header
```

I understand that it fails due to having huge files in the repository( which we do have) , but why does it Not fail when I clone the same repository? Because I am able to clone the repository successfully. Shouldn't The same objects  be packed at the time of a clone request?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To expand a bit on [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21361370/1256452)...

First, it may help to note that `signal 9` refers to `SIGKILL` and tends to occur because the remote in question is a Linux host and the process is being destroyed by the Linux ["OOM killer"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html) (although some non-Linux systems behave similarly).

Next, let's talk about objects and pack-files.  A git "object" is one of the four types of items that are found in a git repository: a "blob" (a file); a "tree" (a list of blobs, their modes, and their names-as-stored-in-a-directory: i.e., what will become a directory or folder on when a commit is unpacked); a "commit" (which gives the commit author, message, and top level tree among other data); and a "tag" (an annotated tag).  Objects can be stored as "loose objects", with one object in a file all by itself; but these can take up a lot of disk space, so they can instead be "packed", many objects into one file with extra compression added.

Making a pack out of a lot of loose objects, doing this compression, is (or at least can be) a cpu- and memory-intensive operation.  The amount of memory required depends on the number of objects and their underlying sizes: large files take more memory.  Many large files take a whole lot of memory.

Next, as VonC noted, `git clone` skips the attempt to use "thin" packs (well, normally anyway).  This means the server just delivers the pack-files it already has.  This is a "memory-cheap" operation: the files already exist and the server need only deliver them.

On the other hand, `git fetch` tries, if it can, to avoid sending a lot of data that the client already has.  Using a "smart" protocol, the client and server engage in a sort of conversation, which you can think of as going something like this:

- "I have object A, which needs B and C; do you have B and C?  I also have D, E, and F."
- "I have B but I need C, and I have D and E; please send me A, C, and F."

Thus informed, the server extracts the "interesting" / "wanted" objects out of the original packs, and then attempts to compress them into a new (but "thin") pack.  This means the server will invoke `git-pack-objects`.

If the server is low on memory (with "low" being relative to the amount that `git-pack-objects` is going to need), it's likely to invoke the "OOM killer".  Since `git-pack-objects` is memory-intensive, that process is a likely candidate for the "OOM killer" to kill.  You then see, on your client end, a message about `git-pack-objects` dying from `signal 9` (`SIGKILL`).

(Of course it's possible the server's OOM killer kills something else entirely, such as the bug database server. :-) )

Comment: Detailed and instructive, as usual. +1

Answer (score 3):

It can depends on the protocol, but [`Documentation/technical/pack-heuristics.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b594c975c7e865be23477989d7f36157ad437dc7/Documentation/technical/pack-heuristics.txt#L196-L208) points out a first difference between clone and fetch.

> In the other direction, fetch, `git-fetch-pack` and `git-clone-pack` invokes `git-upload-pack` on the other end (via ssh or by talking to the daemon).
>
> There are two cases:
>
> - `clone-pack` and `fetch-pack` with `-k` will keep the downloaded packfile without expanded, so we do not use thin pack transfer.
> - Otherwise, the generated pack will have delta without base object in the same pack.
>
> But `fetch-pack` without `-k` will explode the received pack into individual objects, so we automatically ask `upload-pack` to **[give us a thin pack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1584190/6309)** if `upload-pack` supports it.

So in term of protocols, [`Documentation/technical/pack-protocol.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b594c975c7e865be23477989d7f36157ad437dc7/Documentation/technical/pack-protocol.txt#L346-L393) illustrates that a fetch can return *a lot more* data than a git clone.