# How to solve "aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side"?

Tags: git

I am trying to pull in my spring MVC project. And afterthat, the pull didn't work, I am getting the error message in eclipse message box: "aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side".
Could anyone give me a hand please?
I have this error message from eclipse:

[image]

Comment: also, I have followed the forum with this reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170317/git-pull-error-remote-object-is-corrupted, which mentionned to execute these three command:  git config --global pack.windowMemory "100m"
git config --global pack.SizeLimit "100m" 
git config --global pack.threads "1" , but they didn't work,

Answer (score 1):

Your Git is talking to another Git.  That other Git is (presumably) on a different machine, far away somewhere over the Internet.  According to your Eclipse software, the problem is *on the other machine*.

There is nothing you can do on your side.  You must log in to the other machine and examine the repository there.  The server may have logs about what it found, or you can just navigate to the repository in question and run `git fsck`.

Edit per comments (see below): Eclipse is hiding a key bit of information.  A clone run from the command line prints:

```
remote: Counting objects: 55755, done.
error: pack-objects died of signal 9
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: early EOF
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
fatal: index-pack failed
fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
```

Although it's not obvious, the *second* line is the key here: **Died of signal 9** means that on the *server*, the `git pack-objects` commands was killed by the "OOM killer".

A google search for `git server OOM killer site:stackoverflow.com` turns up:

- [git fetch fails due to pack-object failure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21359777/1256452): what's going on
- [What killed my process and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/726690/1256452): general advice about Linux OOM killers
- [Git out of memory and then fatal - early EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28156058/1256452): Adrian adds a swap file on the Linux server, which fixes the problem

and more.

Comment: Hello again, thank you for our response, but I forget to mention I can commit to the server side.

Comment: Doesn't really matter if *you* can do that. Apparently your Eclipse can't. Find out why your Eclipse can't talk to the server. This is probably not a Git problem, but rather an Eclipse problem—try running command-line Git directly to find out.

Comment: I try to clone from the repository of the server, and I had some error in console: remote: Counting objects: 55755, done.
error: pack-objects died of signal 9remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: early EOF
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.fatal: index-pack failed
fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.

Comment: Aha, now we're getting somewhere. Signal 9 is SIGKILL on a Linux system (and others) and indicates that the server is low on memory. Give "git  server oom killer site:stackoverflow.com" to Google and look at the various answers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of issue, the reason was that the root on the linux server ran out of space. Luckily the git(lab) server was running on a different partition, so no git repo was damaged.

Solution: clean up/freeing some disk space on the root.