# GIT manages file by storing diff?

Tags: git

I attended a lecture class there i understood that whenever a change is made in a file ,GIT  doesn't store the diff rather it stores the new snapshot of the modified file in its new version. 
I have few questions :

1. My understanding of the concept is correct or not ?
2. if yes, then How storing entire file is better than storing diffs between two version of same file ?Is it not a wastage of space ?
3. Why we need to **add** before doing a **commit** on a file, why cant it be done directly? (i know this is slightly off the hook)

please correct me if i misunderstood anything.

Comment: Your best option would be reading a few chapters form the progit book http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started (exactly covers your questions)

Comment: The third question has nothing to do with the first two. You should better split it off, or even better, read it up in the book @Isantipov linked, which explains the concepts of git. The first two questions should be answerable here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mix up revision and storage.

- revision is, as opposed to other VCS, a complete file system. Git doesn't build back the current revision with the delta from the previous ones: it references everything.
  See [Git Basics](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics)

[image: http://git-scm.com/figures/18333fig0105-tn.png]

- storage: however, once committed, the storage will eventually compressed and make [delta for pack files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9478566/6309) (or for [thin pack files when transferring over the network](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1584190/6309))

Since Git is at its core a *content* manager, two files with the same content will be actually stored once.

As [for the index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689838/difference-between-head-working-tree-index-in-git/3690796#3690796), it allows you to prepare the next commit, not only with files you want to add, but in some case, with *part* of files you want to add.
See also:

- "[what does the git index EXACTLY contain?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4086986/6309)" and
- "[What does 'adding to the index' really mean in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25352119/6309)"

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, but periodically git will compress older files and store them as pack files that will merge files together and compress them, but you really don't need to worry about this I think.
2. If you don't change a file, it's not duplicated during a commit.
   So most files only exist once, only modified files are stored as new files. combined with the periodical pack compression this should keep storage in check.
3. ( somewhat unrelated to the storage format ) **Staging changes** or **adding to the index** or simply **adding** ( all equivalent things ) allows you to select what changes you want to commit. It basically enables you to split up several changes over multiple commits, it's really very useful. ( you can use [`git add -A`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html) to add all changes in 1 command)

More info on pack files:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Packfiles