# Netbeans Git client through VPN

Tags: git, netbeans, vpn

When using the Git client from Netbeans to push to a Git server through a VPN connection I get a timeout error. I guess the push took too long because either slow connection or big file size. What I would like to know if there is a way to modify the default timeout.

Comment: Do you get this error when you use git in a shell/terminal window? I don't know if Netbeans implementation supports it but I think thin packs might help. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583904/what-are-gits-thin-packs

Comment: I second @kush's idea of testing outside of NetBeans first.  If the VPN is doing something funny with http/https (they often do) you could see if the git server you're using supports SSH.

Comment: Do you need to set up proxy? if you have one you have to set it or it will not work.

Comment: Hi, I get an error when using the client integrated in Netbeans. Kush, I'll check the link and I let you know. Thank u.